# how to get the href of a product if item name and colour matches inside the same 'inner-article'

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How can I get the href of a product if item name and colour matches inside the same 'inner-article'

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` in C#.

Here is the current code to get item name and colour:

```
var ItemName = doc.DocumentNode
            .SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class,'inner-article')]//h1//a[contains(., '" 
                                 + txtKeyword.Text + "') or contains(., '" 
                                 + txtKeyword + "')]");

var ItemColour = doc.DocumentNode
             .SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class,'inner-article')]//p//a[contains(., '" 
                                 + txtColour.Text + "') or contains(., '" 
                                 + txtColour.Text + "')]");
```

Here a photo:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to this code:

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault(a => a.HasClass("inner-article") && a.InnerText.Trim().Equals("valueFromTxtbox"))?.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

Here is `HasClass` method:

```
public static bool HasClass(this HtmlNode node, params string[] classValueArray)
        {
            var classValue = node.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
            var classValues = classValue.Split(' ');
            return classValueArray.All(c => classValues.Contains(c));
        }
```